# Filter the measure based on the other measure value

Tags: powerbi, dax, powerbi-desktop, daxstudio

Please help me I am trying to filter out the data in 23 Qty Blank Values Only Based on the check Month Wise .

```
Check Month Wise = IF(ISBLANK([23 Qty]),"D",IF(ISBLANK([22 Qty]),"N",BLANK()))
```

This is a Measure.

I have tried this dax

```
23 Qty Blank Values Only = If( check Month Wise=Blank(), 23 Qty,0)
```

But its not working subtotal level its getting item code level only

[Please find the Image here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OnKc3.png)

In the subtotal level also filter the values

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need to use `SUMX` so that it is calculated per row of your relevant table.

Try something similar to:

```
23 Qty Blank Values Only = 
  SUMX(
    DISTINCT('Financial Data Month'[PAC ITEM CODE]),
    IF(ISBLANK( [Check] ), [23 Qty], 0)
  )
```

Comment: Thank you for commenting I have tried the Sumx but its completely getting Zero is there any other method Please help me .

Comment: What's the expression for `[23 Qty]` ?

Comment: 23 Qty = CALCULATE(sum('Financial Data (3)'[QUANTITY SHIPPED]),'Financial Data (3)'[YEAR]=YEAR(TODAY())-1,'Financial Data (3)'[EXTERNAL INTERCOMPANY]="External")

Comment: Which table have you used for the `SUMX`? Is it the same table that is used in the Rows of the Matrix? See if the updated answer solves it (added `CALCULATE(..)` around the measures).

Comment: 23 Qty Blank Values Only = CALCULATE(SUMX('Financial Data (3)',IF([Check Month Wise]=BLANK(),[23 Qty],0)))  The same table which I have used can I share my pbix file with you

Comment: Sure, share a link to your PBIX (via OneDrive, Google Drive, Drop Box etc...)

Comment: Just confirm two things: 1. Your Matrix rows are coming from `'Financial Data (3)'`, and 2. You've tried the CALCULATE version above in the updated answer.

Comment: Okay give me some time I will share the link

Comment: Thank you It is working  Is there any alternative for solution sum x Just for knowing?

Comment: Not really, not if you want to check on a measure result. Please mark answer as Accepted for the benefit of all.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback! You need at least 15 reputation to cast a vote, but your feedback has been recorded.  when I try to accept the solution which I am getting Actually this is my First Question

Comment: Click on the "check mark" under the vote arrows: https://i.stack.imgur.com/97kjx.png